# Are you allowed to have fork as a for condition?

Tags: c, linux, fork, exit

this question was on last year's exam and i have never seen anything like this in my life. I know what fork does, what it returns, but this... i can't even compile this

what is displayed when running the C code below? How many processes appeared in total (including the initial process)? Sketch the tree of these processes, indicating next to each process that displayed something the displayed value (in parentheses) Justify the answers.

```
int x=0;
for(fork();!fork();exit(x))
    for(!fork();exit(x);fork())
        for(exit(x);fork();!fork());

printf("%d\n",++x);
```

Comment: What attempts have you made to understand what's happening, and to try to solve it yourself? The only part of this that asks a question outside of the exam question is the title.

Comment: I will note that the code is wrong as written, since the condition of the second `for` has a type of `void`, so as you say it won't compile.

Comment: so it's a trick question, it's not supposed to do anything?

Comment: Maybe it's a trick question, designed to waste the time of students who go straight for trying to diagram an illogical and pointless forking program. Maybe it's just a mistake, professors make those too, and I've seen my fair share of mistakes on exams.

Comment: If you do want to practice a question like this, fixing it so that it will actually compile, the approach I would take is to rewrite the `for` loops as `while` loops, so that it's easier to see when the `fork`s happen, and which ones have their return value used.

Comment: In the second and third loops, the ‘!fork()` in the first and third part of the loop controls are identical to using `fork()` — the negation has no effect on the code.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the headline question — are you allowed to have `fork()` as a `for` condition? — is "yes" because it is a function that returns an `int`.

The answer to the unasked question — are you allowed to have `exit(x)` as a `for` condition? — is unclear, but using the standard C header `<stdlib.h>` to declare `exit()` means that the answer is "no" because `exit()` does not return at all, and is declared not to return a value (nominally, it returns `void`).

The code shown doesn't list the headers included.  If it includes `<stdlib.h>` to declare the standard C function `exit()`, the code won't compile.  If it doesn't include the header `<stdlib.h>`, the code can only be compiled without warnings under C89/C90 rules where undeclared functions are assumed to return an `int` value.

*Nomenclature*: For the purposes of this answer, the three components of the `for` loop condition are `expression-1`, `expression-2` and `expression-3`.  The initial process is designated P0 — child processes are designated P1, P2, …

So, working under the assumption that `exit()` and `fork()` are both inferred to return `int` (and `printf()` likewise, though using a varargs function like `printf()` without a function prototype in scope leads to undefined behaviour), and that `exit()` behaves like the standard C `exit()` and terminates the process, and that `fork()` creates a new process, returning zero in the child process and non-zero in the parent process, we can make multiple observations.

- The only value that can be printed is `1`, but that is only printed if any of the myriad processes executes the `printf()`.
- In the second loop — `for(!fork();exit(x);fork())` — the `!` operator is irrelevant; the value returned by that `fork()` is never examined.
- Similarly, in the third loop — `for(exit(x);fork();!fork())` — the `!` operator is irrelevant.
- The first loop evaluates its `expression-1` which results in two processes running, P0 and P1.  Both processes run the first loop's `expression-2`, forking again, so there are now 4 processes, P0, P1, P2 (child of P0) and P3 (child of P1).
- For P2, the result of `!fork()` is 1 so it executes the loop body and similarly for P3; for processes P0 and P1, the result of `!fork()` is 0 so the loop terminates; each of P0 and P1 executes the `printf()` statement and exits.
- For processes P2 and P3, IF the loop body (loops 2 and 3) terminate ordinarily, the corresponding `expression-3` will be evaluated and the process will exit without printing anything.  Note that it is a big"if"!
- There is nothing except their PID and PPID values to distinguish P2 and P3; the argument for one applies equally to the other.
- When P2 executes loop 2, the `expression-1` creates a new process P4.
- Both P2 and P4 evaluate the condition, which causes the process to exit with status 0 (success).  The body of loop 2 (which is loop 3) and the `expression-3` are not executed, so further analysis of loop 3 is unnecessary.

So, there were a total of 6 processes — P0..P5 (P5 being the child of P3).

The output is two lines containing `1` — probably.  The interleaving of the results is not determinate.  There will be two `1`'s and two newlines in the output; the first character will be a `1`; the last character will be a newline.  In theory, the middle two characters could appear in either order, but two neat lines is the most likely output.

Consider the code below code, which is a minor variant of the original.  However, it compiles cleanly under C11, C18, etc without complaints from Clang (`Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)`) set fussy:

```
clang -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
      -Wstrict-prototypes fork17.c -o fork17
```

The code should compile without warnings using these options.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#undef exit

/* This could (should?) include _Noreturn in the definition because it doesn't return */
static int terminate(int x)
{
    exit(x);
    return x;
}

#define exit(x) terminate(x)

static void notification(void)
{
    printf("PID = %d\n", getpid());
}

int main(void)
{
    atexit(notification);
    int x = 0;
    for (fork(); !fork(); exit(x))
        for (fork(); exit(x); fork())
            for (exit(x); fork(); fork())
                ;

    printf("%d\n", ++x);
    return 0;
}
```

The dance with `#undef exit` undoes any macro definition of `exit()` but leaves the function declaration in place.  The function `terminate()` is defined to return an integer value, but calls the real function `exit()` which terminates the process before the return occurs.  The `#define exit(x) terminate(x)` means that the calls to `exit()` in the `main()` function actually call `terminate()` instead, but the result is the same as if `exit()` were called except that it ensures no undefined behaviour.

The `notification()` function is a simple function called when a process exits normally — it identifies which process is exiting, giving a way to check on the number of processes created by the program.

I've added an appropriate top and tail for function `main()` and called `atexit(notification);` to get notified when processes exit.  I removed the irrelevant `!` operators from the second and third loop controls — `clang` complained that the expression result was unused.

One example run produced:

```
1
PID = 31569
1
PID = 31570
PID = 31571
PID = 31572
PID = 31573
PID = 31574
```

This confirms that 6 processes were created and two lines containing `1` were printed, as stated in the deconstruction of the code.

This is a bad exam question because you have to make a number of questionable assumptions to come up with the answer that the exam-setter expects.